# Can I raise an exception if return value not zero?

Tags: python, exception, return-value

I would like to call functions until one returns nonzero, as in the following:

```py
def a():
    return 0

def b():
    return 1

def c():
    return 0

def seq:
    if a() != 0:
        raise BaseException

    if b() != 0:
        raise BaseException

    if c() != 0:
        raise BaseException

seq()
```

Here, `a` and `b` are called, but not `c`. If `c` were before `b`, then all three would be called, and if `b` were first, then only `b` would be called.

I want this to be more concise. It would be easy if `b` threw an exception instead of returning a nonzero value, because I could use a `try` block. But it doesn't, so I can't.

How do I remove the redundant code here? Is there a block like `try` that could handle this?

Answer (score 3):

Because Python supports [first-class functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function), you can do this with a `for` loop.

Python lets you put the functions in a list, then iterate over them like any other value.

```py
def a():
    return 0

def b():
    return 1

def c():
    return 0

for func in [a, b, c]:
    if func() != 0:
        raise BaseException
```